# How many dragons exist in the Light Novels so far?

Tags: unlimited-fafnir

I tried to find a list of the dragons online, but so far only found [this stub on wikia](http://juuou-mujin-no-fafnir.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons). As hecatoncheir is not even listed there, it is not complete.

Can I get a list of the dragons that appeared on the Light Novels with their alleged powers?

Comment: The list is more or less complete, except that Blue is Hecatoncheir and Gold is phoenix. There is Silver Tiamat also.